# I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and NetBeans 8.0.2 - getConnection always underlined RED

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm hoping that you can help me?

I'm currently working on an application that will be programmed in NetBeans 8.0.2 and will have SQL Server 2014 as the backend database application.

I am trying to get the NetBeans app to talk to the SQL database app and although I feel I have run the processes of creating the linking etc. correctly, I cannot get the getConnection to any state apart from underlined RED.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

I have added my call below:

```
Connection con = null;   
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=KeyProp","sa");
    System.out.println("Connected");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception :" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to call a `getConnection` method that does not exist (`getConnection(String, String)`).

You have the following choices:

- [`getConnection(String url)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-)
- [`getConnection(String url, Properties info)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-)
- [`getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

So the most likely solution is to use

```
getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://...", "sa", "your-sa-password)
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me Mark. I have tried that solution, but still with no luck. Lower down you mentioned driver on Class Path could not be correct or not installed. I am sure that I have done this, however perhaps I missed a step. Is there perhaps anyway I can contact you in a private capacity to discuss this further, or is that not permitted on here?

Comment: @Don no, sorry, there are hundreds of questions about class not found exceptions, or read a basic tutorial on the java class path. It is a fundamental concept of java that you need to understand.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. All is good then. I will work on this further and see if I can find where the issue is. If I find it, I will post here to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it's underlined, but in your connection string the `password` is definitely missing

Comment: Thank you, I have however tried with or without a password and the current password is blank, so have omitted it. Even with the password there I get no joy in having the getConnection underlined removed.

When running the app I get the following error, which I am assuming is because of the issue with the getConnection:
Class Not Found Exception :com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: @Don That means you don't have the driver on your runtime classpath.